# EasyPermissions.requestPermissions and initialization of OSMaps

Tags: permissions, location, openstreetmap

Please help me fix my mistake with the initialization OSM and request permission
After granting permission OSM doesn't work.

**part of code from MainFragment:**

```kotlin
private fun requestPermissions() {
    if (hasLocationPermissions(requireContext())){
        return
    }
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "You need to accept this permission to use this app.",
            REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
       )
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "You need to accept this permission to use this app.",
            REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
        )   
    }
}


private fun permissionListener(){
    pLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){
        showToast("Permission is $it")
        initOSM()
        checkLocationEnabled()
    }
}

private fun checkPermission(){
    if(!isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
        permissionListener()
        pLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
    }
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    const val REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1
    fun hasLocationPermissions(context: Context) =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT\<Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        }else{
            EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
        }
    }
}

override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {
}
    
override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: MutableList<String>) {
    if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this,perms)){
        AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show()
    } else {
        requestPermissions()
        checkPermission()
    }
}
```

### **`Extension Function:`**

```kotlin
fun Fragment.isPermissionGranted(p: String): Boolean {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
    activity as AppCompatActivity, p) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

#### `previous code (`*`this code correct works only my phone`*`)`

```kotlin
private fun registerPermissions() {
    pLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
    ){
    if (it[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] == true) {
        initOSM()
        checkLocationEnabled()
        checkLocPermission()
    } else {
        showToast("dont permission to use this app")
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private fun checkLocPermission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        checkLocPermissionAfterQ()
    }else{
        checkLocPermissionBeforeQ()
    }
}

private fun checkLocPermissionAfterQ() {
    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        && checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
    ) {
        initOSM()
        checkLocationEnabled()
    } else {
        pLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
            )
        )
    }
}

private fun checkLocPermissionBeforeQ() {
    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
        initOSM()
        checkLocationEnabled()
    } else {
        pLauncher.launch(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        )
    }
}
```

## Extension

```kotlin
fun Fragment.checkPermission(p: String): Boolean {
    return when (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity as AppCompatActivity, p) -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
```